# Mxnet C++ prediction vs Python

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet

We are mainly using C++ and want to use Mxnet. I found some discussion that C++ prediction or future extraction slower than Python version ?

Is there any experienced Mxnet C++ engineers to expedite this subject including the a decent way to using Python generated Mxnet model in C++?

prediction.cpp in Mxnet is not so user friendly.

Comment: this is what I strugled before. Why there is a clear way to use mxnet models from c++ ? compiling cpp example feature_extracitom.cpp asking nnvm/c_api.h whis not in Makefile and the path ..

Answer (score 1):

MXNet was built with several frontend languages in mind, and I see no reason why prediction made using Python should be faster than predictions made using C++.

There is a gap in documentation on how to use MXNet with C++ at the moment mostly because the majority of the MXNet community is using Python (same holds true for the deep learning/machine learning field in general). One relevant C++ example you could look into is [here](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/tutorials/c++/basics.html).

If you would like to contribute more examples on how to work with MXNet using C++, you are more than welcome to submit [Pull requests](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/pulls).

Comment: I hope it should be at least slightly faster according to our past experince . On the other hand we want to compile prediction side instead of giving python code which is user tends to messing up .. Best

Comment: Does this answer still accurately describe the situation in late 2021? What about the Dive into Deep Learning interactive book?